# Cómo seleccionar columnas después de haber usado la función mutate()

Tags: r, select

A través de la función `mutate()` he creado una nueva columna en un marco de datos ya existente y, al mostrar los resultados en Markdown, esta columna aparece en la última posición.

Como quiero que se vea claro, estoy tratando de seleccionar solo las dos primeras columnas y la última (decade) para que el resultado sea más visible.

Sin embargo, aparece un error, ya que R obviamente dice que la variable `decade` no existe en mi marco de datos (el original).

¿Cómo puedo usar select dentro de este código para obtener un resultado y que no me siga saliendo el error?

Las columnas que quiero seleccionar son: `event_name`, `year`, `decade`.

```
mutate(wdsf, 
    decade = case_when(
        year < 1930 ~ "1920s",
        year < 1940 ~ "1930s",
            year < 1950 ~ "1940s",
            year < 1960 ~ "1950s",
            year < 1970 ~ "1960s",
            year < 1980 ~ "1970s",
            year < 1990 ~ "1980s",
            year < 2000 ~ "1990s",
            year < 2009 ~ "2000s"))
```

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Aquí hay preguntas y respuestas en español. Traduce tu pregunta. En inglés [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 0):

## Datos, por ejemplo:

```
wdsf <- data.frame(
    event_name = paste0(
        LETTERS[ sample.int( 26, 100, replace = TRUE ) ]
      , as.character( sample.int( 4000, 100, replace = TRUE ))
    )
  , year = 1910 + sample.int( 110, 100, replace = TRUE )
)
```

## Cómo seleccionar con `dplyr::select`

```
require( dplyr )

mutate( wdsf 
  , decade = case_when(
        year < 1930 ~ "1920s"
      , year < 1940 ~ "1930s"
      , year < 1950 ~ "1940s"
      , year < 1960 ~ "1950s"
      , year < 1970 ~ "1960s"
      , year < 1980 ~ "1970s"
      , year < 1990 ~ "1980s"
      , year < 2000 ~ "1990s"
      , year < 2009 ~ "2000s"
    )
) %>%
  select( c( event_name, year, decade )) %>%         # <----- *****
    head

#  event_name year decade
#1      N2864 1916  1920s
#2      S2150 1971  1970s
#3      J1812 1932  1930s
#4      N1575 2003  2000s
#5       N382 1929  1920s
#6      U2648 1948  1940s
```

## Referencia y mas ejemplos:

Subset columns using their names and types: [Tidyverse Select](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select.html)